# Convert one full String to ints and words as an interpreter in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a Forth interpreter in Haskell.  There are many sub problems and categories to accomplish this, however, I am trying to accomplish the most basic of steps, and I have been at it for some time in different approaches.   The simple input case I am trying to get to is `"25 12 +" -> [37]`.   I am not worried about the lists in Forth are backwards from Haskell, but I do want to try and accommodate the extensibility of the input string down the road, so I am using `Maybe`, as if there is an error, I will just do `Nothing`.

I first tried to break the input string into a list of "words" using Prelude's `words` function.  From there I used Prelude's `reads` function to turn it into a list of tuples `(Int,String)`.  So this works great, up until I get to a command "word", such as the char `+` in the sample problem.

So how do I parse/interpret the string's command to something I can use?
Do I create a new data structure that has all the Forth commands or special characters?  (assuming this, how do I convert it from the string format to that data type?)

Need anything else, just ask.   I appreciate the help thinking this through.

Comment: You could use a tagged union like `data Input = IInt Int | IWord String` including all the different types you want to use to suppport the interpreter, and so turn your input String into `Input` before executing it.

Answer (score 2):

`read` is essentially a very simple string parser. Rather than adapting it, you might want to consider learning to use a parser combinator library such as [Parsec](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsec).

There are a bunch of different tutorials about parser combinators so you'll probably need to do a bit of reading before they 'click.' However, the first example in [this tutorial](http://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/parsec-generally.xhtml) is quite closely related to your problem.

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

play :: String -> Either ParseError Integer
play s = parse pmain "parameter" s

pmain :: Parser Integer
pmain = do
  x <- pnum `chainl1` pplus
  eof
  return x

pnum = read `fmap` many1 digit

pplus = char '+' >> return (+)
```

It's a simple parser that evaluates arbitrarily long lists:

```
*Main> play "1+2+3+4+5"
Right 15
```

It also produces useful parse errors:

```
*Main> play "1+2+3+4+5~"
Left "parameter" (line 1, column 10):
    unexpected '~'
    expecting digit, "+" or end of input
```

If you can understand this simple parser, you should be able to work out how to adapt it to your particular problem (referring to the list of generic combinators in [the documentation for `Text.Parsec.Combinator`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.0.0/docs/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html)). It will take a little longer at first than using `read`, but using a proper parsing library will make it much easier to achieve the ultimate goal of parsing Forth's whole grammar.